# How lookup value from a table, using another table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have question about lookup data from a table,...
there is a table that save 4 fields from users : id, name, username, email
I have another table that save 10 more not required fields from users : phone, and...

now I want to lookup the Id from **table 1** in **table 2** and show the phone number in the table too.
Note : ID is a shared code between table 1 & 2

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","blah","blah","blah");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Here is 2 tables
mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM q7fbn_users");
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM q7fbn_user_profiles");

echo "<table border='1', table style='float:center' align='center'>
<tr>
// Here is the table 1 fields
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>E-mail</th>

// Here is the phone number that i want lookup from table 2
<th>Phone</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo "<tr align='center'>";
// Here is the table 1 fields
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
// Here is the phone number that i want lookup from table 2
  echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that, that in your row there will be only the data from the user table, because you are fetching data from the `$result` only.
You need to join them:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM q7fbn_users LEFT JOIN q7fbn_user_profiles ON q7fbn_users.id = q7fbn_user_profiles.userId");
```

Of course you need to change the `q7fbn_user_profiles.userId` to your name of your field what conatins your user id in that table.

**EDIT:**

Based on OP table structure of the profile:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "blah", "blah", "blah");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// Here is 2 Database
mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM q7fbn_users";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
echo "
<table border='1', table style='float:center' align='center'>
    <tr>
    <!--  Here is the database 1 fields -->
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <!-- Here is the phone number that i want lookup from database 1 -->
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    //Now you can use the $row['id'] what is the id of the user
    //so create another query to get the phonenumber.
    $sql = "SELECT profile_value FROM q7fbn_user_profiles"
        . " WHERE user_id = ". $row["id"] . ""
        . " AND profile_key = 'profile.phone'";
    $profileRes = mysql_query($con, $sql);
    //Get the phonenumber from the table2
    $phoneRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($profileRes);
    //Initialize the phonenumber, maybe there are not phonnumber for this user.
    $phoneNumber = '';
    if ($phoneRow) {
        $phoneNumber = $phoneRow['profile_value'];
    }
    echo "<tr align='center'>";
    // Here is the database 1 fields
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    // Here is the phone number that i want lookup from database 1
    echo "<td>" . $phoneNumber . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Need more detail on how join 2 tables in query, i did the code to my php, but nothing shown in the table...

Comment: show me the structure of the user_profile table please.

Comment: See my edited code, and my comments, and please try to understand what i've did.

Comment: do you know why some values in profile_value are like this :"\u062f\u0627\u0646\u0634\.......... ? It was UTF8 but the value is not!

Comment: I think those are json_enoded arrays or strings with UTF encoding.

Comment: I already convert Collation to utf8_persian_ci, it was general. but it didn't fix the issue. thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, i know that.  That does not matter. If there are only latin characters in a string, there are options, where you can code it to hexa characters. When you decode it, it will be normal strings again.